# How to get times new roman font in beamer?

Tags: beamer, fonts

I am using Warsaw theme. I want my beamer slides to have times new roman font.

Comment: This is your 7th question without a MWE.

Comment: I will improve henceforth

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you're using pdfLaTeX to compile your document, you should load the `beamer` class with the option `professionalfonts` and issue an instruction such as `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` to load a Times Roman clone.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass[professionalfont]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Hello World. $1+1=2$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Didn't know the `newtxtext` package so far. Good to know.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - The `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages, which are maintained by Michael Sharpe, represent a significant and systematic development over the `txfonts` package.

Comment: @Mico- gives an error: File 'newtxtext.sty' not found. I suppose I need to upload this package

Comment: @Qwerty - If you don't have `newtxtext` in your TeX distribution, you could try `mathptmx` or `txfonts` -- or, as you mention, simply download and install the `newtxtext` package.

Comment: @Mico-Great! `txfonts` helps. I will try `newtxtext` as well!

Comment: @Qwerty - Do note that `txfonts` is quite old; you'll be much better off if you can install the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages.

Comment: @Mico- Yep, I am installing them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55642/discussion-between-qwerty-and-mico).